# Uploading json to DynamoDB getting string error

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have Json file contains the the below row:

```
{
  "tenant_EntityID": {
    "s": "12345"
  },
  "enrtyDate": {
    "s": "7.9.2000 14:53:45"
  },
  "first_name": {
    "s": "Y7M9"
  },
  "last_name": {
    "s": "NUYE"
  },
  "gender": {
    "s": "male"
  },
  "birth_incorp_date": {
    "s": "9.3.1999 14:49:44"
  },
  "email": {
    "s": "0XPY9E@C20R.com"
  }
}
```

When I am trying to load it to DynamoDB by the below code:

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')

table = dynamodb.Table('Entities')

with open("C:/data/bigJson1.json") as json_file:
    Entities = json.load(json_file, parse_float = decimal.Decimal)
    for Entity in Entities:
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'tenant_EntityID':Entity['tenant_EntityID'] ,
                'enrtyDate': Entity['enrtyDate'],
                'first_name': Entity['first_name'],
                'last_name': Entity['last_name'],
                'gender': Entity['gender'],
                'birth_incorp_date': Entity['birth_incorp_date'],
                'email': Entity['email']
                }

        )
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Freedom/Comparing json file.py", line 39, in <module>
    'tenant_EntityID':Entity['tenant_EntityID'] ,
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: In python we use `lowercase_with_underscores` for variables and `CapitalCase` for types. `Entity` should be `entity`, etc.. That threw me for a second.

Comment: Add a `print(Entity)` just after `for Entity in Entities:` and tell us the output.

Comment: If the only thing your JSON file contains is that dictionary that would explain the error. Set `Entity = json.load(...)` and remove the for loop. Only do the loop if you have a list of dictionaries, i.e. there must be square brackets. If there are no square brackets but you have a JSON object on each line, then you need to do `for line in json_file: entity = json.loads(line)`

Comment: If I have 2 rows and i am running again, i am getting an error:

Comment: File "C:/Freedom/Comparing json file.py", line 33, in <module>
    entities = json.load(json_file, parse_float = decimal.Decimal) File "C:\Users\meitale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw) File "C:\Users\meitale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 367, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)

Comment: What do you mean by 'rows'? Is your file just `{...}<newline>{...}` or is it `[{...}, {...}]`? What is the message for that error?

Answer (score 1):

When you read the JSON string into Entities the result is a dict, with keys `"tenant_EntityID"` and so on. The statement `for Entity in Entities` iterates over that dict, giving you the keys of the dict, which are strings.

It looks as though you need something more like this:

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')

table = dynamodb.Table('Entities')

with open("C:/data/bigJson1.json") as json_file:
    Entity = json.load(json_file, parse_float = decimal.Decimal)
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            'tenant_EntityID':Entity['tenant_EntityID'] ,
            'enrtyDate': Entity['enrtyDate']['s'],
            'first_name': Entity['first_name']['s'],
            'last_name': Entity['last_name']['s'],
            'gender': Entity['gender']['s'],
            'birth_incorp_date': Entity['birth_incorp_date']['s'],
            'email': Entity['email']
            }
        )
```

It's just my own guess that you want the values associated with the `'s'` keys.

You say that it fails "when you run with 2 rows." Most likely the JSON should really be cast as a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary.

Comment: can it be connected to the python version? i am running with 3.6